# Sorting an array of data on frequency of occurence

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of values which I want to sort on the frequency of occurence. For now I manage to count the occurences but I can't find out how to sort them ...  whats wrong?

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {// graphs and prefixes defined here
            var list = new Array();
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data.results.bindings, function() {
                    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                        if(!($.trim(v.value) in list)) {
                            list[$.trim(v.value)] = 0;
                        }
                        list[$.trim(v.value)] = list[$.trim(v.value)] + 1;
                    });
                }); 
                list.sort(function(a, b) { 
                    return a.value - b.value;
                }); 
                var c = 0;
                for (var i in list) { 
                    var html = '<li data-value="'+list[i]+'">'+ (c++) +' '+i+' ( '+list[i]+' )'; 
                    $("#list").append(html); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the `a.value - b.value`?  I mean, isn't the `list` variable an array numbers?  `a.value` or `b.value` is invalid... isn't it?

Comment: no list is an array of srings

Comment: Your `list` variable looks like it's holding the counts for occurrences.  So, those are numbers.  It can't be strings.

Comment: The code above displays the occurrences in ascending order, right? And you want it to display unique values (``v.value``) sorted according to frequency in ascending order?

Answer (score 2):

```
function orderByOccurrence(arr) {
    var counts = {};
    arr.forEach(function(value){
        if(!counts[value]) {
            counts[value] = 0;
        }
        counts[value]++;
    });

    return Object.keys(counts).sort(function(curKey,nextKey) {
        return counts[curKey] < counts[nextKey];
    });
}



> orderByOccurrence(['a','c','a','c','a','c','c','c','c', 'pllee'])
> ["c", "a", "pllee"]
```

This will work on other primitives including mixing primitives but they will all get converted to strings.

```
> orderByOccurrence([1,1,1,1,1, 0, -5, -5, false, false, false])
> ["1", "false", "-5", "0"]
```